# Is there any solution to run Google Plus Posting(Share interactive post) in emulator (Android)

Tags: android, share, google-plus, google-play-services, posting

I am integrating Google Plus in Android App,But I encountered problem during Sharing Post on Google Plus in emulator Because `It requires Google Plus installed on Emulator.` But We can't add Google Plus App on Emulator.

I know that it run only in device but still searching for solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services is available on AVDs as long as you're using a new enough version, see http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> [To test your app you can use...] The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform
>   based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Comment: I already installed Google play service..I want to run Google Plus posting on emulator which requires to install Google Plus app in emulator.But i can't installed Google Plus App on device.See my  updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Download Google+ apk from [here](http://wccftech.com/article/download-google-plus-apk-android/) 
copy and paste it to your (adt...\sdk\platform-tools) directory
open command prompt and expand upto your "\sdk\platform-tools" then write command 
`adb install com.google.android.apps.plus-1.apk`
 and press enter
 
see pictures below for your help
[image: sample image for command prompt] 
[image: image of emulator you can see Google+ app is installed]
its succesfully installed on Emulator.

Comment: @Ponting follow the simple steps from my answer you can install Google Plus app on Emulator :)