# Sign in with google+ not working

Tags: android, google-plus

I have successfully created a google+ signin button. I have followed  [link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) google developer site procedure for this. But when I click on the button nothing is happening. I have attached code below

GoogleAcivity.java

```
    public abstract class GoogleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ExampleActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;

    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
                .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)  // recommended login scope for social features
                // .setScopes("profile")       // alternative basic login scope
                .build();
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // Progress bar to be displayed if the connection failure is not resolved.
        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
            }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button && !mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
            } else {
                try {
                    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {

                    // Try connecting again.
                    mConnectionResult = null;
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
      if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
        // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
        // connection dialog.
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
          try {
                   result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
           } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                   mPlusClient.connect();
           }
        }
      }
      // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
      mConnectionResult = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");
    }
}
```

What I missed in the code. Please help..

Comment: Did you checked your Logcat for any errors or warnings?

Comment: @Sankar, No logcat shows nothing when i click on the button

Comment: I am using android 4.2.2 is it causes the problem?

Comment: is it working in other android os version ?

Comment: @Robert What problem does it have ?

Comment: @GrIsHu I don't know what I did wrong...

Comment: Are you testing your application in emulator ?

Comment: @GrIsHu yes I'm using emulator

Comment: Make sure your emulator contains the Google+ application installed.

Comment: @GrIsHu, checked, I'm using the target Google APIs, API level 17

Comment: Have you checked in your emulator Google+ is installed or not ?

Comment: @GrIsHu,No in my emulator google+ is not installed. Can I install it in emulator?

Comment: Check out the post to install google plus in emulator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276682/is-there-any-solution-to-run-google-plus-postingshare-interactive-post-in-emul @Robert

Comment: @GrIsHu I Tested it in a device, but no change.. I couldn't even find the mistake I had done..

Comment: @GrIsHu,@Sankar Ganesh, what should be the package name while creating the client id, whether its my application package or its com.google.android.gms.samples.plus?

Comment: Its should be the pacakge name which you have defined for your application. @Robert

Comment: @GrIsHu my googleActivity.java class is saved inside com.example.MyApplication package and application contains other packages also. What should I write?

Comment: The main package of your application which contains your launcher actiivty.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says `TAG ="ExampleActivity"` the `"ExampleActivity"` should be `GoogleActivity`.

Comment: `TAG` is only used for logging, it doesn't affect click behavior.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public abstract class GoogleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ExampleActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;

    private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
                .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
                .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)  // recommended login scope for social features
                // .setScopes("profile")       // alternative basic login scope
                .build();
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // Progress bar to be displayed if the connection failure is not resolved.
        mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");
            }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button && !mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
            } else {
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find any difference in your code from my code